# i want to change the box size how to use animate method?

Tags: javascript

i want to change the box size and
how to use animate() method? I tried but it's not work...
where is the problem??

```
<style>
.box {
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 background-color: red;
  }
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div class="box"></div>
<script>
 const boxes = document.querySelector(".box");
 boxes.addEventListener("click", boxes1);
  function boxes1() {
    boxes.animate({
      width: "300px"
    });
  }
 /*boxes.click(function(){
  boxes.animate({width:"300"});
   }); << it also not work */
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here iam using Javascript and HTML to change the box width while click on it

```js
 function change_width()
 {
    document.getElementById("box").style.width='300px';
 }
```

```css
#box {
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="box" onclick="change_width()"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to animate the box on click

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    .box {
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      background-color: red;
      transition: width 300ms ease-in;
    }
  </style>
  <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="box"></div>
<script>
  const boxes = document.querySelector(".box");
  boxes.addEventListener("click", boxes1, false);

  function boxes1() {
    this.style.width = "300px";
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `animate()` method is part of a library called [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) which you need to include using `<script></script>` tags in your `<head></head>` to use.

In order to use jQuery methods, you need to apply them to a jQuery object. Here I have used `$('.box')` to select elements with the class `box`. In the function, you can then use `$(this)` (which is a jQuery object) to refer to the box clicked and animate it accordingly.

See example below:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <!-- Include jQuery to use mthods such as .click & .animate -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    .box {
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      background-color: red;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <script>
    $('.box').click(function(){
     $(this).animate({width:"300"});
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```